# Dividir un número de cualquier longitud java

Tags: java

Tengo que saber como dividir un número en dígitos sin utilizar la conversión a String, es decir, hacerlo todo con int.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce un número");
    String num = sc.next();
    String[] dig = num.split("");
    for (int i = 0; i < dig.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(dig[i]);
    }
}
```

Solo sé hacerlo utilizando el split, pero necesito hacerlo sin usar arrays ni String.

Comment: Cual es el problema de convertirlo a string, dividirlo y volver a convertirlo a int.

Comment: En ningún momento hay que utilizar Strings ni convertir nada, tiene que ser todo en int

Comment: ya puse la respuesta abajo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es sencillo, aquí lo tienes haciendo solo divisiones:

```
        String num = sc.next();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(num);
        int[] digitos = new int[num.length()];
        int i = digitos.length - 1;
        while (number > 0) {
            //System.out.println( number % 10); //el residuo es tu número empezando por el último, osea en reversa, lo puedes ir guardando en un array de integers empezando por el último.
            digitos[i] = number%10;
            number = number / 10;
            i--;
        }

        for(int j=0; j < digitos.length; j++){
            System.out.println(digitos[j]);
         }
```

Comment: Y como se haría para guardarlo en un array empezando por el último?

Comment: acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, si te sirve marcarla como resuelta :)

Comment: No se puede sacar el length de un array de integers, me da error

Comment: actualizado, es sin ()

Comment: Se sigue imprimiendo desde el último

Comment: si, se imprime desde el último, pero se está guardando desde el primero en el arreglo de digitos, voy a corregirlo para que veas

Comment: ahora que tal? ya lo actualicé

Comment: En este caso al introducir un número se imprime primero un 0 y el último digito del número no se imprime. Lo del 0 se arregla cambiando la j por 1, pero no sé como hacer que imprima el digito que falta

Comment: ok dejame probarlo, es que lo hice al ojo :P

Comment: ya actualicé el código, deja como estaba el j = 0 ,  el error era que digitos[i] = number%10;  , debe ir antes de hacer la division /10

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: de nada :)  y sigue practicando

Answer (score 0):

Así lo hice yo (soy nuevo en esto)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lee = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n_inv = 0, resto;
    System.out.println("Digite un numero");
    int n = lee.nextInt();
    int falt = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1;) {
        resto = falt % 10;
        n_inv = n_inv * 10 + resto;
        falt = falt / 10;
        if (falt == 0) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(n + " inverso es: " + n_inv);
}
```